# Java Socket Closes After Connection?

Tags: java

Why does this port/socket close once a connection has been made by a client?

```
package app;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class socketServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port = 3333;
    boolean socketBindedToPort = false;

    try {
        ServerSocket ServerSocketPort = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("SocketServer Set Up on Port: " + port);
        socketBindedToPort = true;

        if(socketBindedToPort == true) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;

            try {
                clientSocket = ServerSocketPort.accept();//This method blocks until a socket connection has been made to this port.
                System.out.println("Waiting for client connection on port:" + port);
                /** THE CLIENT HAS MADE A CONNECTION **/
                System.out.println("CLIENT IS CONENCTED");
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Accept failed: " + port);
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Socket did not bind to the port:" + port);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: " + port);
        System.exit(-1);
    }



}


}
```

Comment: Just a note, your println s are in the wrong order. You should put "Waiting for client connection..." before clientSocket = ServerSockPort.accept();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, but I am pretty sure it's because there is nothing else left in your program. Once ServerSocketPort.accept(); finishes, the program hits the end of main and closes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Stream to it that reacts to the client.

try this:

```
Socket accepted = serverSocketPort.accept();
InputStream inStr = accepted.getInputStream();
```

Comment: How will I add a listener that reacts when the client has made a connection to it?

Comment: @Matthew sorry I meant Stream. You have to read the stuff the client sends you.

Answer (score 0):

The program is running absolutely fine. It *will* stop as soon as a client connects or the **ServerSocket** times out. What is your goal here?

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew.

IMHO, Joel has the closest answer to your question.

"The connection is closed because the program exists after it accepts a connection"

Usually, the accept is run in a loop so that, the server keeps listening to connection requests on the port